# npm run build conflict for fullstack nextjs if using generateStaticParams()

Tags: reactjs, next.js

im trying out the Nextjs13 app directory.

- I've build api with routes (api directory ) where it gets data from mongoDb successfully,
- I've fetched data in server side rendering method, successfully.
- The build went as expected.

When i added generateStaticParams() to get Ids,the build shows a conflict:

- Either, it can't  generate Ids because Api is not running.
- Or, build stuck because dev is running.

Is there a way to make it work ?